# Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing.php on line 30

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, datediff

I am computing for the span of days and store it in the database for further use. This is for the reservation form that I would like to code and I made a simple form similar to it for testing if the span of days would be stored in the database but all I get is this error..

**Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing.php on line 30**

I'm just a beginner. I already checked it at the other sites but nothing would fit at my problem. I would highly appreciate all the help. Thank you.

```html
<?php

$localhost = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbase="testing";

$conn = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbase);

//check connection
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
 die('Sorry we are having a problem.');
}


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{

$dateOfReserv = $_POST['dateOfReserv'];
$dateUntil  = $_POST['dateUntil'];


 $date1=date_create($dateOfReserv);
 $date2=date_create($dateUntil);
 $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
 $diff->format("%days");


  $sql="INSERT INTO `tbldate` (datestart, dateend, spanofdate) 
   VALUES ('$dateOfReserv', '$dateUntil', '$diff')";

  
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "New record created successfully";

  } 
  else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  } 

  $conn->close();

   
  exit();




}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>testing for inserting date in xampp server</title>
</head>

<body>


<form method="POST">
<ul>
 <li>
   <label for='dateOfReserv'>Date of Reservation<span>*</span></label><br />
   <input type='date' id='dateOfReserv' name='dateOfReserv' placeholder='Date of Reservation' size='40' />
 </li>
 <li>
   <label for='dateUntil'>Until?*</label><br />
   <input type='date' id='dateUntil' name='dateUntil' placeholder='End Date of Reservation' size='40' />
 </li>
 <li>
   <input type='submit' name='submitbtn' value='Send Date' />
 </li>

</ul>

</form>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
$diff = $diff->d;
```

Instead of:

```
$diff->format("%days");
```

Also note your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, and if the dates aren't formatted you'll get errors from date_create/date_diff too!

Comment: oh. thanks. but what if i want to add another day? I mean, if I select the date today and 24, the code will give me 2, what if I want to count the date today too? how.. is it like this... 
 $diff = $diff->d;
$diff = $diff + 1;

Comment: but I use an input type date, how would it be vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: Not all browsers implement `type=date`, also, if I do a `curl -X POST --data 'dateUntil=<vulnerable string>'` your form is irrelevant :) -- in short, never trust the client

Comment: is that so? okay, I will keep it in mind and add some validation. thank you! :)

Comment: I try selecting other month but it doesn't give the right answer, like, i select today and march 30, it doesn't give the right answer..

Comment: @BlackSkull use $diff = $diff->format("%a") to get the total number of days, otherwise you can access $diff->m (months) * 30 + $diff->d (days)